# Is the commutation relation in quantum mechanics right?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, commutator

$$[ \hat X, \hat P_x\hat F(x)\hat P_x] =\frac{\hbar}{i}[\hat F(x)\hat P_x+ \hat P_x\hat F(x)]$$
It's given in the book "Basic Quantum Mechanics" by R.L. White.
Maybe I am doing something wrong. 
What I am getting is:
$$[ \hat X, \hat P_x\hat F(x)\hat P_x] =-\frac{\hbar}{i}
[\hat P_x\hat F(x)+2\hat F(x)\hat P_x]$$
This is how I was doing:
\begin{align}
   [ \hat X, \hat P_x\hat F_x\hat P_x]\psi & = \hat X \hat P_x\hat F_x\hat P_x\psi
- \hat P_x\hat F_x\hat P_x \hat X \psi \\
        &= \cdots - \frac{\hbar^2}{i^2} \frac{\partial}{\partial x}(F_x\psi+F_xx
\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial x}) \\
& = - \frac{\hbar^2}{i^2} (F'_x\psi+2F_x \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial x}) \\
&= -\frac{\hbar}{i}(\frac{\hbar}{i}\frac{\partial F_x}{\partial x}\psi+
2F_x \frac{\hbar}{i}\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial x}) \\
&= -\frac{\hbar}{i} (\hat P_x\hat F_x \psi + 2\hat F_x \hat P_x \psi) \\
& = -\frac{\hbar}{i}[\hat P_x\hat F(x)+2\hat F(x)\hat P_x]\psi 
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try using the identity $[\hat{A},\hat{B}\hat{C}\hat{D}]=[\hat{A},\hat{B}]\hat{C}\hat{D}+\hat{B}[\hat{A},\hat{C}]\hat{D}+\hat{B}\hat{C}[\hat{A},\hat{D}]$. Then, according to your question, we have
$$ \begin{align*}
[\hat{X},\hat{P}_{X}\hat{F}(\hat{X})\hat{P}_{X}]\Psi&=[\hat{X},\hat{P}_{X}]\hat{F}(\hat{X})\hat{P}_{X}\Psi +\hat{P}_{X}[\hat{X},\hat{F}(\hat{X})]\hat{P}_{X}\Psi+\cdot\cdot\cdot
\end{align*} $$
Then you can use some of the known commutators that you can find in standard quantum mechanics textbooks. As for commutators with $\hat{F}(\hat{X})$, you need to Taylor expand it as a function of operators and find a pattern.

Comment: Thank you.
But I don't understand how to deal with the $\hat F(x) $!
Can you kindly write in detail? 
Isn't $ [\hat X, \hat F(x) ] =0$?

Comment: If you Taylor expand $\hat{F}(\hat{X})$ and take a commutator with $\hat{X}$, you get zero.

Comment: Yes, I get it just after writing my previous comment. Thanks!
By the way, can you kindly suggest some good, rich resources about these stuffs? I am a beginner level QM learner.

Comment: Resource recommendaiton would depend on your mathematical background.

Comment: I am a physics undergrad, gonna start my junior year. I have had math courses including differential equations, special functions, matrices, complex variables.

Comment: The most popular QM textbook is "Introduction to Quantum Mechanics" by Griffiths. You can also study "Principles of Quantum Mechanics" by Shankar. The latter is more advanced but has a rather lengthy introductory chapter on maths prerequisites.

Comment: Thank you. I have already started reading from the books by Griffiths and Zettili.